# Who was Uri, Betzalel's father?

Tags: parashat-ki-tisa

We find Betzalel's grandfather Chur was willing to give his life to try preventing the nation from creating the golden calf, but what was so special about Uri who merited having a son like Betzalel? (Shemos 31:2)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55619/discussion-on-question-by-njm-who-was-uri-betzalels-father). Feel free to post specific suggestions for improvements of this post here and to continue to discuss possible alternative questions there.

Answer (score 3):

The [Ohr HaChaim HaKadosh](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.2?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=he) citing Shemos Rabbah explains that the mention of Uri serves as part of a hint explaining the purpose of the Mishkan.

(*Source from [Sefara.org](http://www.sefaria.org)*)

(*Partial Quote*)

> ראה קראתי בשם. אולי שיכוין לומר שיראו רמז הענין בשמו ושם אבותיו, בצלאל שעשה צל לאל, בן אורי שעשה מקום לאשר אור לו, בן חור שעשה ישראל בני חורין מעון העגל ....
>
> ***See I have called by name:** perhaps (G-d) meant to say that (G-d) hinted with (Betzalel's) name and the name of his fathers.**Betzalel** because he "provided shade" (by building the Mishkan) **Son of Uri** for he made a place to provide light for Him (G-d). **Son of Chur** because he made (the nation of) Israel free from the sin of the (golden) calf....*

---

<sub>Additionally, in my humble opinion that it can be implied that "calling by name" (as mentioned in 33:2) by singling out an individual is to call refer to them by their given name as well as their father's but it needs further research to make that assertion (See the [Chizkuni](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.2?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=he) as well)</sub>